# APNS production certificate problems

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I m facing some issues in creating apns production certificate.Please refer the image

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxfzyuwnxk8qan6/Screen%20Shot%202015-12-21%20at%201.05.01%20pm.png?dl=0]

My old certificates are with name "APNs Production iOS" the first in image. Now when I am created new apns production certificates its displaying "Apple Push Services" and when I installed this on server notification are also not coming.

Is there process change in developer account. Why the name is showing different. Please help to understand the issue.

Comment: apple itself changed name for push certificates no need worry about name. if you facing issue means you have done some mistake while certificate creation process.

Comment: If this is correct Narayana then that would be the answer we are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get complete idea of your problem as per description, but i think you are not able to create proper production certificate of APNS for particular app.

In that case try to follow the steps mentioned in this tutorial step by step. you have created development certificate, so you should not have to follow the first 3 steps. you can follow step 4 to create apns certificate and choose the mode for production.

https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/how-to-create-apns-certificate

Generally the steps are :

1. you need to create **.csr** file using **key-chain access.**
2. you have enabled the push-notification for your app id, at there you need to **upload the .csr file** , and create the certificate for **Apple Production iOS Push Services**

Make sure you select App id, then click on Edit and then follow the steps. it should look something like this

May be it helps.

[image]

Comment: There is no problem creating development certificate. My problem is why production certificate is created as "Apple Push Services". It should be created as "APNs Production iOS"

Comment: Try the following steps.

1. you have to select the app-id for which you want to create production certificate of APNS.

2. On click edit, Your can configure the push notification enabled and then from there , you will get option to upload a .csr for production apns certificate for that particular file.

complete those steps and check the result.

Comment: Thanks Krupanshu.. I have tried the same also but result is same. I am not sure if apple has change something for production certificates apns now.

Comment: Yes. may be it changed when Universal Push Notification Client SSL Certificate option provided by apple by which we can generate common certificate for sandbox and production.

Answer (score -2):

you have done some mistake while making certificate. it should look like this.
[image]

can u specify steps u follow for creting this certificate

Comment: 1. under certificate i clicked on production.
2. Clicked on +
3. Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production) selected
4. Bundle id selected.
5. CSR uploaded